# Backbone and checking response of loggin

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

I use a bacbone in a first time. And i try to login
There is a php.code

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if ($data) {
    $name = $data->{'uname'};
    $passwd = $data->{'passwd'};
    echo ($name == "myname" && $passwd == "mypass") ? "Login success" : "Wrong name or password";
}
```

And a backbone code

```
var modelLogin = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'login.php'
});
modelLogin.save({
    uname: "myName",
    passwd: "myPassww",
});
```

How to see (e.g with alert or console.log) thw words "Login success" or "Wrong name or password"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone can help you with that.

Every request to server using backbone.model, uses from behind jquery(ajax). So use Backbone or Jquery in this case have no difference

```
//Inside your model
LoginUser:->
    @fetch(
         success:=>
             trigger 'authenticated'
         error:=>
             trigger 'invalidUser'
    )
```

Try to not use save to user authentication, use save only when you post(save data) on server.

The best approach in this case could be fetch the content to server and return the userID or something about the user if the user login and password are both correct.

If you'd like to know the status code returned from server, you can get it from fetch. Like this:

```
//Model
  LoginUser:->
    result = @fetch(
                success:=>
                    trigger 'authenticated'
                error:=>
                    trigger 'invalidUser'
    )
```

more info here http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to use the model Backbone for this operation as a response from the server contains no information to fill the model. In your case, just use the Ajax request